# Error during restart wildfly server : ”/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java”: No such file or directory

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04, wildfly-8

I am configuring Wildfly server on 80 port using autobind in ubuntu using link http://www.solomonapenya.com/2016/10/08/wildfly-on-port-80-for-http-443-for-https-using-authbind/ .At Step 9 from the mentioned link, i am getting following error.

”/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java”: No such file or directory

please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Isn't the mentioned error message "No such file or directory" clear enough? What else do you need?

Comment: Do make that folder structure `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java` & then retry.

Comment: this structure "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java" already exist.

Comment: Are the permissions set correctly? Have you installed oracle manually or via apt?

Comment: @triplem I have used "sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer" command to install java. and what is correct permission?

Comment: Permission: The linux user which wants to execute the JVM must have execute rights on the file ´/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java´ and each of the folders above. Concrete: the x-flag must be set on the files 'other' right, or at least on the 'group' right if the user belongs to that group.

Comment: @Heri Following is permissoin with, is that wrong or i need to changes owner, who is executing wildfly instance. root@ip-172-31-22-236:/opt/wildfly/bin# cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin root@ip-172-31-22-236:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin# ll total 904 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 17 17:08 ./ drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Nov 17 17:08                                     
 **../ -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8464 Nov 17 17:08 java***                                      
 I have change the user i.e. wildfly yet its giving same error in both case i.e. through root user as well wildfly user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"eval authbind -deep \”$JAVA\” -D\”[Standalone]\” $JAVA_OPTS"

above statement pasted into standalone.sh file at path ../wildfly/bin from the link [http://www.solomonapenya.com/2016/10/08/wildfly-on-port-80-for-http-443-for-https-using-authbind/] following step no. 8

I just used **\$JAVA\ instead of \”$JAVA\”** in above statement then it is working fine.